# Handling dead keys in Android KCM

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm using library [Extra Physical Keyboard Layouts](https://github.com/varzan/extra-keyboard-layouts) which is able to add new keyboard layouts to the device. Don't confuse it with whole new keyboards like SwiftKey, Samsung Keyboard etc.
This library is using [KCM files](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-character-map-files) which is Android standard for keyboard layout files.
I have my custom layout (originally KLC file) which I converted to KCM.

But these two main things about dead key are missing:

```
\u030c (ˇ) + \u0075 (u) should produce \u016f (ů), but now it is producing \u01d4 (ǔ)
But for example:
\u030c (ˇ) + \u0074 (t) result \u0165 (ť) is fine

\u030c (ˇ) + \u030c (ˇ) should produce \u003d (=).
Basically double pressing key EQUALS should produce \u003d (=)
```

The problem is that afaik there is no way how to handle dead keys in KCM file and are handled automatically by the OS.

Is there a way how to solve mentioned problems in KCM file or any other way **without** creating custom keyboard like SwiftKey etc.?
Mentioned KLC and KCM files can be found [here](https://github.com/varzan/extra-keyboard-layouts/issues/14).
Thank you

Comment: KCM dead keys handling topic was created in the Android issue tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234852543